# Display unlisted value in select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<select>` element populated with the acceptable values via `ng-options` and bound to a model with `ng-model`. It is possible that the model is set to a value that is not acceptable. (It used to be acceptable but no longer is.) In this case AngularJS renders the `<select>` as if it had an empty item selected.

Is there a way to have it render the selected value even if it is not listed in `ng-options`? I know I can put a default `<option>` inside the `<select>`. It's better than displaying an empty item, but it's a static string. I'd like to have the invalid *value* displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I think that you will be able to achieve this with the combination of ngInit directive to set up initial value (it can be missing from the allowed options list) and ngShow to hide it once valid option is selected.

Something like this:

```
<select 
    ng-init="preselected = selected"
    ng-change="preselected = null"
    ng-model="selected" 
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
    <option value="" ng-show="preselected">{{preselected}}</option>
</select>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/lUTR0pHDPecU0OUUwjzt?p=preview